# paypal express checkout without passing the token to server

Tags: javascript, node.js, paypal, paypal-sandbox, express-checkout

This is stripe checkout look like

Users pay at the client then if succeed you pass ur token to the server then the charge happens at the backend.

```
$http.post('/stripe',{stripeToken:token.id,qty:qty,user_email:user_email}).then(function(response){})
```

But it paypal's express checkout the flow end solely at the client side. That's strange. Is that even secure?